# Refreshing page with meteor iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Here is the problem :

I am currently programming a chatapp based on what i found on github (https://github.com/sasikanth513/chatDemo)
I am refactoring it with iron-router.

When I go to the page (clicking on the link) I get an existing chatroom (that's what I want)
When I refresh the page (F5) I get a new created chatroom ! (what i want is getting the existing chatroom ...)

Here is the code in ironrouter :

```
Router.route('/chatroom', {
  name: 'chatroom',
  data: function() {

    var currentId = Session.get('currentId'); //id of the other person
    var res=ChatRooms.findOne({chatIds:{$all:[currentId,Meteor.userId()]}});
    console.log(res);
    if(res){
      Session.set("roomid",res._id);
    }
    else{
      var newRoom= ChatRooms.insert({chatIds:[currentId, Meteor.userId()],messages:[]});
      Session.set('roomid',newRoom);
    }

  }
});
```

You can find my github repo with the whole project : https://github.com/balibou/textr

Thanx a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route data depends on `Session` variables which will be erased after a refresh. You have a few options but the easiest would be to put the room id directly into the route: `'/chatroom/:_id'`. Then you can use `this.params._id` to fetch the appropriate `ChatRooms` document. Note that you could still keep `'/chatroom'` for cases where the room doesn't exist, however you'd need to redirect to `'/chatroom/:_id'` after the insert.

Comment: Hmmm... can you add the attempted code to your question and explain in more detail how it didn't work?

Comment: in fact i let it in the client and no more in the router ... thks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

In meteor, the `Session` object is empty when the client starts, and loading/refreshing the page via HTTP "restarts" the client. To deal with this issue, you could persist the user's correspondent id in a Meteor.user attribute, so that you could easily do:

```
Router.route('/chatroom', {
  name: 'chatroom',
  data: function() {
    var currentId = Meteor.user().profile.correspondentId;
    var res=ChatRooms.findOne({chatIds:{$all:[currentId,Meteor.userId()]}});
    console.log(res);
    if(res){
      Session.set("roomid",res._id);
    }
    else{
      var newRoom= ChatRooms.insert({chatIds:[currentId, Meteor.userId()],messages:[]});
      Session.set('roomid',newRoom);
    }
  }
});
```

This would work, with the proper permissions, but I would recommend not allowing the direct update of that value on the client (I don't know if you want users to be able to override their correspondentId). So if you want to secure this process, replace all that code with a server method call, where your updates are safer.

Another (and more common case) solution was given by David Weldon, if you don't mind having ids in your URL (and therefore not a single url)

Comment: Thanks for your time ! I tried with your solution, but now when I click on the link it creates me a new chatroom ...

Comment: Yeah come to think of it, you need to store the other user's id actually. Will edit my answer.

Comment: in fact i let it in the client and no more in the router ... thks for your time :)